# Google Storage: No support for Expect: 100-continue with PUT?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-storage

When trying to upload an object to Google Storage using PUT, the server seems to completely ignore an "Expect: 100-continue" header (at least it never sends a 100 continue until the connection times out).

On closer inspection, the docs at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods?hl=en, actually recommend using 100-continue only when describing POST, yet at the same time recommend using PUT for uploads whenever possible.

What is the motivation here? Is Google Storage really not supporting 100-continue for PUT uploads? And if so, why would I want to use PUT instead of POST when it forces me to do potentially pointless uploads of data?